# Making a Button and Text Change Repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button and some text on the page and I am trying to change both the button text and the page text when the button is clicked and I am trying to do this with jQuery. It works the first time the button is clicked, but then it does not change back when clicked again. Here is my code:

```
var button = $('.button');
var div = $('.div')
button.on('click', function() {
    if(button.html('Hello World') && div.html('Hello World')) {
        button.html('What\'s Up');
        div.html('What\'s Up');
    }
    else if(button.html('What\'s Up') && div.html('What\'s Up'))  {
        button.html('Hello World');
        div.html('Hello World');
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't use `.html`, use `.val`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first condition will always return true because it is setting the value of `div` and `button`, not checking for equality. Try:

```
if(button.html() == 'Hello World' && div.html() == 'Hello World') {
```

Would probably be better to use `text()` instead of `html()` since you aren't actually setting HTML

Comment: Thanks for the help, your suggestion worked. I also see now what you mean by checking for equality, as opposed to changing the value. 

Answer (score 0):

```
var text1 = 'Hello World', text2 = 'What s\'up ?';

$('button').click(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == text1) {        
    $(this).text(text2);
    $('div').html(text2);
   } else {         
     $(this).text(text1);
     $('div').html(text1);
   }

});
```